# Is the use of the indefinite article 'a' with the word 'staff' considered standard

Tags: articles, indefinite-articles

The word *staff* can apparently refer to a member of a group of service personnel. ([Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/staff?s=t) mentions this as one of the meanings of *staff*: *a member of a staff*.)

I was wondering how native speakers look upon this usage of the word *staff*. For example, consider the sentence *I called a staff aside*. I know a less questionable way to rephrase the sentence might be *I called a staff member aside*. But is the first version acceptable; does it sound outlandish?

Comment: Have you checked a good dictionary?

Comment: I checked three different dictionaries, but couldn't find a definitive answer to the question. I think they were reasonably good dictionaries in other respects.

Comment: "I called the staff aside" sounds good

Comment: Suggesting migration to [ell.se]

Comment: Hmm...the question has been marked as topic. But one of [your commonly available references Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/staff?s=t) mentions this as one of the meanings of _staff_: _a member of a staff_.

Comment: @gkb0986, that entry probably pertains to the usage "He is staff", i.e. as a categorization or role marker. Compare "He is faculty". Note the lack of any article.  The short answer to your question is "no". You cannot say "he is a staff" to mean "he is a member of the staff". If you don't like "member of", consider "one of the staff" or "staffer", as Edwin suggested (though at least here in in the US, that's typically reserved for political or legal staff members).

Comment: @DanBron Thanks for the answer. What I find puzzling though is that a similar entry, for a member of a group, does not figure on [Dictionary.com's page for faculty](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/faculty).

Comment: I've definitely heard it used that way, but maybe it's colloquial in academia, where "staff" and "faculty" are more like castes than roles (as in "Oh, he's just *staff*").

Comment: Your Dictionary.com reference certainly licenses 'I called a staff aside.' = 'I called a staffer aside.' = 'I called a member of staff aside.' While I wouldn't use 'staff' this way myself, I think we need the OED data here. And you're quite correct that 'off-topic as being genref' is an incorrect censure here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Staff is a mass noun; it refers to a (uncountable) group. Prefixing it with the indefinite article still indicates a group, though now the group is unspecified (i.e. indefinite).

In other words, the only time a native English speaker would use "a staff" (when not talking about some kind of walking stick) is in the sense:

> Mary hired *a staff* to handle the wedding, including an event planner, a cook, a photographer, and some ushers.¹

Or:

> *A kitchen staff* usually comprises a head chef, a saucier (or sous chef), a few line cooks, and a dishwasher

Using "a staff" to mean "one of the staff" would be received as awkward and confusing (and a bit dehumanizing, and hence demeaning, to the staff member in question; which means you could use it sardonically in precisely that sense).

---

¹ Though this is perhaps a bad example, because makes it sound like she hired each of those individuals separately; that's certainly possible, but to hire "a staff" carries the connotation that she hired them as a group, that came together (perhaps from a specialized wedding supplier).

Comment: I said the same myself, though without a supporting authority I restricted my opinion to a comment. According to Dictionary.com, the usage of 'a staff' for 'a member of staff' is allowable if not to our liking. I've deleted my inadequate comment.

Answer (score 1):

Although "staff" can refer to an individual person, in modern colloquial
it is used in the group sense. That is why "a member of staff" sounds correct. We automatically interpret that staff is a group, and therefore has "a member".

Similarly, consider "My staff was absent today". Although it does not specify if it is a single person or a group but most people will take it to mean "My entire staff was absent today".

So technically, "a staff", should be correct, but is not common in modern usage.

Comment: That's not the way the word is used with an article. Please check usage examples.

Comment: I'd like to say "Compare 'a jury', which does not mean 'a member of the jury' ", but OP's reference says that 'a staff' CAN be used to mean 'a member of staff'.